# pairwise compare the dataframe rows with python/pandas (positional indexers are out-of-bounds)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to compare every row with the previous one on column value(the name of column of interest is `value`), and if they have the same value I want to delete one of rows.

```
name    value
Mark    True
Anna    False
Steven  True
Karl    False
Peter   False
Laure   True
```

So I want to delete the row with Karl cause his value repeated in the next row

So I tested this code:

```
def clean_limites():
for (idx1, row1), (idx2, row2) in pairwise(limites.iterrows()):
    if row1["value"]==row2["value"]:
                limites.drop(limites.iloc[row1], axis=1)
    print "succefully dropped row1"
return clean_limites
```

my function for `pairwise` :

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

I have following output errow:

```
succefully dropped row1
succefully dropped row1
succefully dropped row1
succefully dropped row1
succefully dropped row1
succefully dropped row1
succefully dropped row1
succefully dropped row1
succefully dropped row1
succefully dropped row1
succefully dropped row1
succefully dropped row1

IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

I'm new in python, so any help will be welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift) to perform the comparison and filter the rows out:

```
In [141]:
df[df['value']!= df['value'].shift()]

Out[141]:
     name  value
0    Mark   True
1    Anna  False
2  Steven   True
3    Karl  False
5   Laure   True
```